# Wave equation in a coupled chiral medium

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, symmetry

I want to find a wave equation propagating in a coupled medium.

Normally, to find a wave equation in an isotropic and sourceless medium, derivations shown below can be done.
$$\nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega \vec B$$
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega \nabla \times \vec B$$
If the constitutive relation can be expressed as shown below, $$ \vec B = \mu \vec H$$
Then we have,
$$\nabla^2 \vec E +\omega^2 \mu \varepsilon\vec E=0$$
However, in a coupled medium, fields can be coupled to each other as shown below which represents the constitutive relations of this medium.
$$ \vec D = \varepsilon \vec E - j\vec B$$ and
$$\vec B = \mu \vec H + j\vec E$$

So, if we try to take curl operator both sides of the Maxwell's equation shown below, we get,
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega \nabla \times \vec B$$
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega \nabla \times (\mu \vec H + j\vec E)$$
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega (\mu \nabla \times \vec H + j \nabla \times \vec E)$$
Which yields,
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega (\mu \nabla \times \vec H + j \nabla \times \vec E)$$
As we stated above, the medium is sourceless. Therefore, the related Maxwell's are
$$\nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega \vec B$$
and
$$\nabla \times \vec H = j\omega \vec D$$
If we reorganize the equation according to Maxwell's,
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega (\mu j\omega \vec D + j (-j\omega \vec B ))$$
If we plug the constitutive relations into the equation, we have,
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega (\mu j\omega (\varepsilon \vec E - j\vec B) + j (-j\omega (\mu \vec H + j\vec E) ))$$
Finally,
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E = \omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \vec E + \omega^2 \mu \vec B + \omega \mu \vec H + j\omega \vec E $$
So, you can see from the equation above, the magnetic field still remains in the wave equation. To obtain a closed form wave equation of the electrical field, the equation derived should only contain the electrical field components. For example, form of the wave equation should be like this
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec E +p\nabla \times \vec E +q \vec E= 0 $$

How can I emit the magnetic fields and obtain a wave equation formed like shown below?

Comment: In an anisotropic medium the quantities $\mu$ and $\epsilon$ become symmetric matrices. You don't seem to have taken that into account. Also where does ${\bf D}= \epsilon {\bf E}-i{\bf B}$ come from?

Comment: Yes, in an anisotropic medium, quantities should be like as you said. Actually, I miswrote the definition of the medium, I do not know where anisotropy came from. Anyway, I edited it, the correct definition of this kind of medium should be "chiral medium". @mikestone

Comment: Also, $$\vec D = \varepsilon \vec E - j \vec B$$ is a constitutive relation which gives a relation between D field and E field. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutive_equation @mikestone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem becomes easier upon a little re-organization.

The relevant Maxwell equations may are
\begin{gather}
  \nabla\times\vec E=-j\omega\vec B, \\
  \nabla\times\vec H = j\omega\vec D,
\end{gather}
where we have assumed time harmonic fields and are using the $e^{j\omega t}$ time convention.  The constitutive equations may be written in terms of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ (trying to reduce the number of fields to solve for) as
\begin{gather}
  \vec D = \varepsilon \vec E - j\alpha\vec B, \\
  \vec H = \frac{1}{\mu}\vec B - \frac{j}{\mu}\beta\vec E,
\end{gather}
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are set equal to one in the original problem.  (I have generalized the problem in case you want a more general solution.)  Substituting $\vec D$ and $\vec H$ into the second of the Maxwell's equations given above and assuming all material properties are uniform in space yields
\begin{gather}
  \nabla\times\vec B - \frac{j}{\beta}\nabla\times\vec E = j\omega\mu\varepsilon\vec E + \mu j\alpha(-j\omega\vec B).
\end{gather}
Multiplying by $-j\omega$ then yields
\begin{gather}
  \nabla\times(-j\omega\vec B) - \frac{\omega}{\beta}\nabla\times\vec E = \omega^2\mu\varepsilon\vec E + \omega\mu\alpha(-j\omega\vec B).
\end{gather}
Substituting the first of the Maxwell equations above then yields an equation entirely in terms of the electric field:
\begin{gather}
  \nabla\times\nabla\times\vec E - \frac{\omega}{\beta}\nabla\times\vec E = \omega^2\mu\varepsilon\vec E + \omega\mu\alpha\nabla\times\vec E.
\end{gather}
Finally, cleaning up a bit yields
\begin{equation}
  \nabla\times\nabla\times\vec E = \omega^2\mu\varepsilon\vec E + \left(\omega\mu\alpha + \frac{\omega}{\beta}\right)\nabla\times\vec E.
\end{equation}